# How to show TextObject on Crystal Report preview/print (Details section)?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

The TextObject **"I. PENGEMBANGAN SISTEM & PROSEDUR"** won't appear on preview/print mode, only appears on design mode. Please help and show me step by steps. I'm new to this Crystal Report, Thanks.

Here is design mode ScreenShot:
[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGMMq.jpg)

Here is preview mode ScreenShot:
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oojsU.jpg)

Comment: Why did you use tags that don't apply? Please edit.

Comment: In preview you are viewing the page header part and I am sure there are more pages go to page where detail section is printing then you can see the missing text.

Comment: @Siva any idea why the text object didnt show on the first page, yeah it's on page 2, but page 1 still have like 40% blank space, sorry im still learning using CR, and thanks for answering my question.

Comment: @RickyLimanto check answer

Answer (score 0):

Crystal report works in following way:

1. Report Header  //Prints once for report same holds true for report footer
2. Page header   //Prints for every page same holds true for page footer
3. Details      //Prints for every record

When certain section doesn't fit in space left in a page then the whole section will be pushed to next page, In your case since you placed your data in detail section and data in detail section doesn't fit in page 1 full section is pushed to page 2, hence you are able to see in page 2 instead of page 1

To solve this `Right Click Page Header --> Insert section Below`

Now take your data from details and place in page header

This is one way of solving the issue, let me know your input

Comment: alr solved this problem by adding Detail b or supress blank section (idk which one or even just rearranging TextObject. But thanks for the reply, every information helps a lot since im new into this :D
alr upvote your answer but my rep still 1...

Comment: @RickyLimanto NP.. happy that my solution helped to solve your problem